# How can I display the most common value sequence in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sequences

Lets say I have a table like this.

```
A | B
-----
1 | 4
7 | 8
1 | 3
1 | 2
4 | 5
3 | 5
2 | 5
7 | 8
```

Even though `1` is the most common value in column `A` and `5` is the most common value in column `B` (which can be checked pretty simply with a `COUNT()`) the result I am looking for is the pair `<7, 8>` since that pair appears twice.

So how can I get the most common value sequence from a table, since I have `n` columns that I need to do this with.

Comment: Are you saying that you're looking for the statistical *mode* of the tuple (A,B)?  In other words the combination of A,B which appears most frequently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select A, B, count(*) as freq
from MyTable
group by A, B
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```